# Reference to another cell breaks ROW() function

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formatted string in excel based on the row number. 
I want for example to have output `001` on first row, `002` on second etc. So I use this function:

```
=TEXT(ROW(), "000")
```

When I use this function on whole column, the displayed result is

```
000
001
002
003
...
```

So far so good, but I want this pattern configurable, so I insert "000" to a cell `A1` and create function like this

```
=TEXT(ROW(), $A$1)
```

Now the `TEXT()` function always return `000` no matter where I use it. Also when I use this function

```
=TEXT(ROW()+10, $A$1)
```

It also returns `000`

What's wrong here? I get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the double quotes that mess it up. Try putting a single apostrophe in A1 followed by the string you want so that you get a text string without the quotes. Or you could remove them with:-

```
=TEXT(ROW(),MID($A$1,2,LEN(A2)-2))
```

or

```
=TEXT(ROW(),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"""",""))
```

Comment: Basically because if you put a string in quotes like "000" in a format code it just interprets it literally and doesn't use it to format the number. If  you put "000" directly in a TEXT statement the quotes are parsed out leaving a string 000 which is OK, but if you put "000" in another cell and refer to it the quotes are still there.